# May be Pyinstaller can't import module

Tags: pyinstaller

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\http://runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main

"**main**", mod_spec)

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\http://runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code

exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main*_.py", line 9, in

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 81, in run

import PyInstaller.building.build_main

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 36, in

from ..depend.analysis import initialize_modgraph

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\http://analysis.py", line 60, in

from ..utils.hooks import collect_submodules, is_package

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks_*init*_.py", line 1104, in

from . import conda as conda_support # noqa: F401

File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\http://conda.py", line 51, in

from importlib_metadata import PackagePath as _PackagePath

ImportError: cannot import name 'PackagePath' from 'importlib_metadata' (c:\anaconda3\lib\site-pack

ages\importlib_metadata_*init*_.py)

I did update pip and pyinstaller but error still appears
Aboce log is from Pycharm terminal

Comment: I am currently facing this issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue for me by installing a specific version of pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.0 --no-build-isolation
```